# Is $y^2=x^3+7$ unsolvable modulo some $n$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

The equation $y^2=4x^3+7$ has no integral solution since $y^2\equiv4x^3+7\pmod4$ has no solution (i.e. has no solution in $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$).

It is well known that  $y^2=x^3+7$ has no integral solution, but is there an integer $n (n>1)$ such that  $y^2\equiv x^3+7\pmod n$  has no solution? If not, how can I prove it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Didn't you just say that it has no solution if $n=4$?

Comment: Yes.  OP is wondering if there *is* a solution for some $n \not= 4$.  (I'm guessing.)

Comment: @user134824, Brian Tung Oops sorry for my typo. I was wondering about $y^2\equiv x^3+7\pmod n$ not $y^2\equiv 4x^3+7\pmod n$

Comment: He asks for where there is not a solution.

Comment: Never mind, I see your correction.

Comment: By the Chinese remainder theorem, if there is such an $n$ then there is such a prime power $n$. A standard calculation of the sum of Legendre symbols $\sum_{x=1}^p ( \frac{x^3+7}p$ will show that $y^2\equiv x^3+7$ (mod $p$) has solutions once $p$ is large enough. So this should be able to reduce your question to a finite computation.

Comment: In case you didn't know, there are two very elementary solutions to $y^2=x^3+7$ [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf) (Theorem 2.1).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [discriminant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant) of $x^3+7$ is $-27\cdot49$. Given a prime power $q$, this discriminant is non-zero in the field $F_q$ unless $q$ is $3,9,27,7,$ or $49$. For other values of $q$, $y^2=x^3+7$ is an elliptic curve over $F_q$, and we can use [Hasse's bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse's_theorem_on_elliptic_curves)

$$|N-(q+1)| \le 2\sqrt q$$

where $N$ is the number of points on the curve. So there are at least $q+1-2\sqrt q$ points on the curve. One of these is the point at infinity; subtracting this, we have at least $q-2\sqrt q$ solutions of $y^2=x^3+7$. This is $> 0$ (and therefore $\ge 1$) for all $q \ge 5$.

So you need only check the cases $q=2,3,4,7,9,27,$ and $49$ to prove that $y^2=x^3+7$ has a solution modulo every prime power. And as Greg Martin points out in a comment, this is enough to establish it for all $n$.

Answer (score 0):

The congruence $y^2 \equiv x^3 + 7 \pmod n$ has a solution for every $n$.  A proof involving Gauss sums is outlined in Exercise 6, pages 21 and 22, of the online document [Characters](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~hlm/nzm/chars.pdf).